# clang-format: Insert new line between braces

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, llvm, clangd

Are there any ways to achieve this (the dot indicates the position of the cursor) in Visual Studio Code by using clangd formatter

```
void foo()
{
   .
}
```

instead of this

```
 void foo()
 {
.}
```

or are there any ways to just use the c/c++ extension formatter from Microsoft while using clangd intellisense in vscode as it asks me to disable the intellisense of c/c++ if i want to use clangd however turning off the intellisense of c/c++ will also turn off the formatter of it.

Comment: Do you want your cursor to be like code sample 1 after hitting enter when the cursor is positioned at the opening brace — or what?

Comment: In VS Code settings, search for formatter configuration, then set up your default formatter either Clang formatter/Prettier or any other without disabling the intellisense.

Comment: Does setting `"editor.formatOnType": true` in vscode settings help?